# Selecting rows of dataframe according to values in column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have some dataframe that I would like to select rows from according to the value of a column using an indexing list.

For example, let's say I want to select the rows of this dataframe that have `['four','two']` in column 'B'`

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['one','two'],['three','four'],['five','six']], columns=list('AB'))
>>      A   B
0   one two
1   three   four
2   five    six
```

Here's my desired output:

```
df.imaginary_column_indexing_function('B', ['four','two'])
>>  A   B
1   three   four
0   one two
```

The best I can do to recreate that snippet is either

```
df.reset_index().set_index('B').loc[['four','two']].reset_index().set_index('index').rename_axis(None)
>>  B   A
1   four    three
0   two one
```

or

```
df.loc[df.reset_index().set_index('B').loc[['four','two']]['index']]
>>      A   B
1   three   four
0   one two
```

Neither of which feel particularly idiomatic, though the latter is the expected output

Comment: Do you mind adding your expected output?

Comment: @rpanai it's in the post, see `df.imaginary_column_indexing_function('B',['four','two'])`

Comment: Do you just need filtering (`df[df.B.isin(['four', 'two'])]`)?   or do you also care about ordering?

Comment: We need the ordering too @Emma

Comment: `flist = ['four', 'two']` and `df[df.B.isin(flist)].sort_values('B', key=lambda x: [flist.index(y) for y in x])`?